# Connoisseur could be used for any knowledge?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

According to wikipedia, a connoisseur is a person who has a great deal of knowledge about the fine arts, cuisines, or an expert judge in matters of taste. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connoisseur

Is there a connoisseur of English (language)?
Does the person really not attend a formal education for achieving it? only by experience of his/her english?

Comment: Note that "connoisseur" is often used in a ironic or sarcastic sense.  In fact, perhaps more often that way than in the literal sense.  One might, eg, describe a child as "a connoisseur of dirt" if he were always covered with said material.   So there is great freedom in applying the term.

Comment: It might help to point out that the word comes from the French verb that means to know or to be familiar with. And that applies to knowing or being familiar with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **connoisseur** can be defined as an "expert able to appreciate a field; especially in the fine arts" (Princeton WordNet).

You are correct, the word is typically used with wine, art, design, and similar, but depending on the context it may be perfectly acceptable to say "He is a connoisseur of English."

This would mean someone who is **not just an expert**, but **someone who appreciates the language and it's beauty, has a passion for it, and "savors" it** (not unlike wine or fine cuisine.)

Consider:

> Edwin Newman, the renowned and extraordinary broadcast journalist **and
>   connoisseur of language**, states it well in *A Civil Tongue*: ...

([source](https://books.google.by/books?id=iPAyVqN7fZMC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=%22connoisseur%20of%20language%22&source=bl&ots=UkeFrSWL_J&sig=RmU_YUEb4oXyW0uE22gES2iiV4U&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false))